# Aptana XML Validation

Tags: xml, validation, aptana

I'd like Aptana to perform basic syntax validation on an xml file (not html, the file doesn't have a DTD).

At the moment it doesn't, although it will correctly identify matching start and end tags and highlight them as a pair, so there's clearly some file processing taking place.

Please tell me I'm missing something obvious!

xmllint will correctly identify unlosed tags, unidentified tags etc.

Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.4.0.201304151603
OS: Linux Mint 14

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + V is supposed to validate XML syntax. Is this not working? Or what are you looking for?

Comment: That works Sarah thanks. (I wish the results were shown inline though, similar to syntax errors in programming languages). Anyway, you should have put your comment as an answer and I would have accepted it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll put my comment as an answer so we don't have this question running around looking unanswered.

Ctrl + Shift + V is the shortcut for XML validation, it can also be found under Commands > XML > Validate Syntax.